# Ember - How to link from parent route to child route when both have array controllers?

Tags: ember.js

I have the following setup. *Each account can have multiple profiles*.

app.js:

```
App.Router.map(function () {
    this.resource("accounts", function () {
        this.resource("profiles", {path: "/:account_id"})
    })
});

App.Account = Ember.Object.extend({
    findAll: function () {
        // Ajax request to fetch data from the server
    }
});

App.AccountsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function () {
        return App.Account.findAll();
    }
});

App.Profile = Ember.Object.extend({
    findAll: function () {
        // Ajax request to fetch data from the server
    }
});

App.ProfilesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function () {
        return App.Profile.findAll();
    }
});
```

accounts.hbs:

```
{{#each model}}
    {{#linkTo "profiles" tagName="li"}}
        {{accountName}}
    {{/linkTo}}
{{/each}}
{{outlet}}
```

profiles.hbs:

```
{{#each model}}
    {{profileName}}
{{/each}}
```

However, this is not working. Whenever I click on one of the account names, nothing shows up in the outlet. And if I pass "this" in {{#linkTo "profiles" this tagName="li"}}, then I get an error message saying that Ember cannot loop through something that is not an Array. How would you go about linking from a parent route to a child route when they both have array controllers and the child template is displayed in the parent's outlet?

Comment: Do you still want a route for a specific profile?

Comment: Yes. So first the user would click on an item in the list of accounts, which then displays the list of profiles for that account. Then the user would select a profile and the profile could appear in yet another outlet.

Comment: I assume your `App.Account` has `profiles: DS.hasMany('App.Profile')`?

Comment: I'm not using Ember data (mainly because, as far as I know, error handling in Ember data is not yet fully functional and I need error handling because I use authentication in my app). So if you can help me without using Ember data, that would be great (if not, I'm also curious to see the solution using Ember data)

Comment: I see. In that case you will have to adapt the code below. For error handling in ED I use the jQuery `ajaxError` function, like so:  `$(document).ajaxError(function(event, jqXHR, ajaxSettings, thrownError) {
  if (jqXHR.status === 401) {
   // error handling code here
  }
 });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

chopper's answer works if the account objects retrieved already had embedded in them the list of profiles. However this is not the case in my setup (perhaps I didn't make that clear enough). The way I solved this is by setting an actions hash in the accounts route with a "fetch_profiles" action handler, triggered from the accounts route and passing the clicked account as the action parameter. The action retrieves the list of profiles with an AJAX call and then redirects the app to the profiles route. So I'm not using a link-to helper in this case.

Answer (score 1):

```
App.Router.map(function () {
    this.resource("accounts", function () {
        this.resource("account", {path: "/:account_id"})
            this.resource("profiles", function () {
                this.resource("profile", {path: "/:profile_id"})
            }
        }
    })
});

App.Account = Ember.Object.extend({
    findAll: function () {
        // Ajax request to fetch data from the server
    }
});

App.AccountsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function () {
        return App.Account.findAll();
    }
});

App.Profile = Ember.Object.extend({
    findAll: function () {
        // Ajax request to fetch data from the server
    }
});
```

accounts.hbs:

```
{{#each content}}
    {{#linkTo "account" this tagName="li"}}
        {{accountName}}
    {{/linkTo}}
{{/each}}
{{outlet}}
```

account.hbs:

```
{{#each profiles}}
    {{profileName}}
{{/each}}
```

Comment: Not working. The list of accounts in the /#/accounts route are displayed, but when I click on one of them, the URL changes to /#/accounts/undefined and so no model seems to be used in the new route. I used ED with RESTAdapter and defined the following models: `App.Account = DS.Model.extend({
 profiles: DS.hasMany("App.Profile"),
 name: DS.attr("string")
});` and `App.Profile = DS.Model.extend({
 account: DS.belongsTo("App.Account"),
 name: DS.attr("string")
});`. I also set up the router like you did. In the App.ProfilesRoute you defined, how is it aware of which account's model to use?

Comment: Try adding `App.ProfileRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function () {
        return this.modelFor('profile');
    }
});`

Comment: Does not help. I would assume Ember does that connection automatically in the background. I don't think we need to specify explicitly that the profile route is related to the profile model.

Comment: Ah I see hat your are after. See the update to my answer (the accounts.hbs part). That should link to your account now and render account.hbs. Does that work?

Comment: I don't have an account.hbs. What would you put in there? The goal would be that by clicking on one of the accounts, it would display the list of profiles for that account.

Comment: See the update to my post. You can simply render the list of profiles in `account.hbs` as above.

Comment: Does the line `profiles: DS.hasMany("App.Profile")` in the account model definition imply that whenever the app goes on a specific account route /#/accounts/12345 then the app will automatically launch a request to the server to load the corresponding profiles? I feel this is almost right, but not there yet. When I click on an account I still get no profile list showing up, as if {{#each profiles}} was looping through an empty array, as if the profiles attribute of the account model was never loaded (and indeed, no trace of that loading on the network tab of the Chrome console).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38645/discussion-between-chopper-and-cwarny)

Comment: I posted the answer that worked for me. Our discussion helped a lot and I realize I didn't insist enough on the fact that my account objects retrieved from the server didn't have embedded in them the profiles (coming from two different tables in the database).